# Encode or Obfuscate PHP code

Tags: php, encryption, obfuscation

This topic has been asked a lot here.
I tried to read some of them, but unluckily i couldn't find the answers.
I would to create my own version of PHP obfuscator like byterun does.
For example:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World";
?>
```

into:

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_X='Pz48P3BocA0KNWNoMiAiSDVsbDIgVzJybGQiOw0KPz4='; 
eval(base64_decode('JF9YPWJhc2U2NF9kZWNvZGUoJF9YKTskX1g9c3RydHIoJF9YLC
cxMjM0NTZhb3VpZScsJ2FvdWllMTIzNDU2Jyk7JF9SPWVyZWdfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GS
UxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfWCk7ZXZhbCgkX1IpOyRfUj0wOyRfWD0wOw=='));?>
```

I'm not looking for a tools how to create the encoded PHP code. I'm looking for how the process to create or encrypt the PHP code. At least a start point to do my research.
Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Ivan

Comment: You realize that this is completely worthless as a theft protection measure? (Just to make sure)

Comment: "Encode or Obfuscate PHP code", "encrypt the PHP code." Encrypt and obfuscate are very different things. Which do you want to do?

Comment: @Pekka: Yes i'm fully understand. I just want to feed my hungry mind.

Comment: @webbiedave i think i encrypt and/or encode is what i want. If you have any clue, i really appreciate it.

Comment: But what for? The only use for this that I can think of is Malware. (Not saying that's your intent, but I don't understand the goal)

Comment: @Pekka: Well the use could be anything. it's only a choice for the user where they use it for good or for bad. And i, i'm just curious of how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very barebones version would be

```
<?php

$po = '<' . '?php';
$pc = '?' . '>';

$input = 'file.php';
$code = file_get_contents($input);

$encoded = base64_encode($code);

$encoded_script = <<<EOL
$po

eval(base64_decode($encoded));

$pc
EOL;

file_put_contents('encoded.php', $encoded_script);
```

The only thing the commercial obfuscators do is add extra levels of obfuscation - rename variables into non-meaningful garbage. Maybe vary the encoding methods, split the source script into multiple chunks and have each one encoded differently, etc...

But in the end, it all boils down to useless garbage that protects about as well as wet toilet paper.